# Convert a uint64_t to a time_point

Tags: c++, c++11, time, c++-chrono

I have a `uint64_t` value which represents nanoseconds since epoch. Now I need to convert this to a `time_point`.

Currently I have this code:

```
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::nanoseconds> uptime(std::chrono::nanoseconds(deviceUptime));
```

Later I want to print something like `Fri Feb 10 15:13:04 2017`. For this I wanted to use this code:

```
std::time_t t = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(uptime);
std::cout << "Device time: " << std::ctime(&t) << std::endl;
```

But I get an error:

```
No viable conversion from 'time_point<std::chrono::nanoseconds>' to 'const time_point<std::__1::chrono::system_clock>'
```

What do I have to do to convert the `time_point` to a format which `ctime` can use? Or is there a better approach for this problem?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point - Look at the template parameters.

Comment: So I need to add the `std::chrono::system_clock` to the template parameter, which gives me this: `std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, std::chrono::nanoseconds> uptime(std::chrono::nanoseconds(deviceUptime));`
But with this I still get the same error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
uint64_t uptime = 0;
using time_point = std::chrono::system_clock::time_point;
time_point uptime_timepoint{std::chrono::duration_cast<time_point::duration>(std::chrono::nanoseconds(uptime))};
std::time_t t = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(uptime_timepoint);
```

Alternatively:

```
std::time_t t = uptime / 1000000000;
```

Comment: Thanks that works. So the function `to_time_t` does not accept nanoseconds? Just a lower precision value like for example milliseconds?

Comment: @Pascal `to_time_t` accepts units of `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point`, whatever resolution that may be. With GNU libstdc++ it is of nanosecond resolution, with clang libc++ it is of microsecond resolution.

Comment: ...which means that you need a cast somewhere with libc++, because `nanoseconds` isn't implicitly convertible to `microseconds`. Whether it's a `duration_cast` or a `time_point_cast` is a matter of taste.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Ah okay :)

Comment: @T.C. That is what `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point` constructor does - it casts to its resolution from whatever duration unit is passed.

Comment: [No it doesn't](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/5iTEm2e8YCAjitRl). That would be a silent truncation and completely contrary to `<chrono>`'s design.

Comment: @T.C. You are right, rolled back to the original answer with the cast.

Answer (score 2):

If you decide you don't want to loose all that subsecond information when printing out, you could use [Howard Hinnant's date library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) (MIT license):

```
#include "date.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    uint64_t deviceUptime = 1486739584123456789;
    sys_time<nanoseconds> uptime{nanoseconds(deviceUptime)};
    std::cout << format("%a %b %e %T %Y\n", uptime);
}
```

which will output something like:

```
Fri Feb 10 15:13:04.123456789 2017
```

`date::sys_time<nanoseconds>` is just a `typedef` for:

```
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, std::chrono::nanoseconds>
```